# Formally smooth morphism of formal schemes $\mathfrak X \to\mathfrak Y$ induces formally smooth morphisms of schemes $\mathfrak X_n \to\mathfrak Y_n$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, ringed-spaces

Let $f:\mathfrak Y \to \mathfrak X$ be a morphism of formal schemes. We say that $f$ is formally smooth if it satisfies the infinitesimal lifting property, that is if for every affine $\mathfrak X$-scheme $Z$ and for every closed subscheme $T\hookrightarrow Z$ defined by a square zero ideal, the natural map
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathfrak X}(Z,\mathfrak Y) \to \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathfrak X}(T,\mathfrak Y)$$
is surjective. The same definition can be stated for morphisms of schemes.

Let $J$ be an ideal of definition of $\mathfrak X$, and let $I$ be an ideal of definition of $\mathfrak Y$ containing $f^{*}(J)\,\mathcal O_{\mathfrak Y}$. This is possible due to the continuity of $f$. For $n\geq 0$, we consider the schemes $\mathfrak X_n := (|\mathfrak X|,\mathcal O_{\mathfrak X}/J^{n+1})$. Then $\mathfrak X$ can be identified with the inductive system $(\mathfrak X_n)$. We can do similarly for $\mathfrak Y$. Then, the morphism $f$ induces a family of compatible morphisms $f_n:\mathfrak X_n \to \mathfrak Y_n$ of schemes.

> If $f$ is formally smooth, is it true that all the $f_n$'s are also formally smooth ?

I have done the following. I fix $n$ and I consider $\mathfrak X_n$-schemes $Z$ and $T$ as above. I also consider a morphism $T\to \mathfrak Y_m$ over $\mathfrak X_m$. Using compositions with $\mathfrak Y_m \hookrightarrow \mathfrak Y$ and $\mathfrak X_m \hookrightarrow \mathfrak X$, I can look at $Z$ and $T$ over $\mathfrak X$ and I get a $T$-point of $\mathfrak Y$ over $\mathfrak X$. By hypothesis, it lifts to a $Z$-point of $\mathfrak Y$ over $\mathfrak X$.

To conclude, I would like to justify that it factors through $\mathfrak Y_m$. That is, if I write $g:Z \to \mathfrak Y$, I would have to check whether the map $g^{*}I^m \to \mathcal O_{Z}$ is zero. Because the structure map $f\circ g: Z \to \mathfrak X$ factors through $\mathfrak X_m$, I know that $g^{*}f^{*}J^m\to \mathcal O_Z$ is zero. Thus, it would be over with **the additional assumption that $f$ is adic**.

But what if $f$ is not adic ? Currently I do not see how I could progress further. However, I have also been unable to come up with a counter example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you more-or-less need $f$ to be adic (and $I=f^*(J)\mathcal{O}_{\mathfrak{Y}}$) to make this work. At least, I can give a relatively general kind of counterexample which very much exploits the non-adicness of $f$.

Here's the counterexample I was thinking of. Take $\mathfrak{X}=\mathfrak{Y}=\mathrm{Spf}(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ and $f$ the identity. For our ideal of definition $I$ of $\mathfrak{Y}$, I want to take the ideal $(p)$, but for the ideal of definition $J$ of $\mathfrak{X}$ I want instead to take $(p^2)$. (Note that $I\supseteq J$ as we wanted.) The map $\mathfrak{Y}_n\to\mathfrak{X}_n$ is then the unique map $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})\to\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}/p^{2n}\mathbb{Z})$, which is certainly not formally smooth for $n\geq1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexander, your counterexample is very convincing and instructive! Often, it ends up being unnecessary to look far away or complicated to get an answer.